# Hide top image with content when scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, fixed

I am wondering how to achieve the effect found in this wordpress theme: http://www.vaexu.com/amada_2/#v-header

I would like to find out how to hide the top image div with the content when scrolling down. I am not sure if it's javascript or CSS magic, I'd appreciate any input from you guys.

Cheers,
Hristo.

Comment: Nobody is hiding anything. You're just scrolling down!

Comment: I think I might be an idiot :) It's probably just the background position: fixed.

Comment: It happens! Next time try using `inspect element` for a better insight :)

Answer (score 0):

The div containing the top image has `background-attachment: fixed;` so that the background image stays in the same place when scrolling.

Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/validide/Cr7wM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7uRbE/2/)

You should set a background to a div with `no-repeat fixed center`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in javascript onscroll event. Register your callback to onscroll event.

```
     window.onscroll = funcRef;
```

You can show/hide DIV element by style.display property

```
   divElement.style.display = "none" // To hide DIV
   divElement.style.display = "" // Again to show DIV
```

This has to done conditionally at right time (You may use other element position)